# Wicket Calling a Servlet

Tags: servlets, wicket

i'm a newbie to wicket framework.
I'd like to call a servlet from a Webpage inside the WebApplication .

And doing some stuff with the servlet response .

There are both in the same container , Tomcat .

I know there's a link with (HttpServletRequest)RequestCycle .
But when and where i do specify which servlet (its name)  to call (because there are many servlet) ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 4):

The Servlet API provides

```
 getServletConfig().getServletContext().getServlet(String);
```

but this method is deprecated since version 2.1 of the specification and the implementations return `null`.

You have two options:

1. make a proper HTTP call to the other Servlet, e.g. with the help of HttpUrlConnection (pre Java 11), HttpClient (Java 11+) or any third party library like Apache HttpComponents/OkHttp/...
2. construct dummy HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse and pass them to RequestDispatcher#include() :

   ```
   ServletContext servletContext =  WebApplication.get().getServletContext();

   RequestDispatcher dispatcher =
       servletContext.getRequestDispatcher("/another/servlet");
   dispatcher.include(dummyRequest, dummyResponse);
   ```

Use dummy ones to not pollute the original ones (the ones for the current http request).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean by dummy ? How to instanciate them ?

Comment: I mean custom impls that override the methods which are used in the other servlet. For example HttpServletResponse#getWriter() could return StringWriter so that you can read the String from it.

Comment: I got it . And what about 'native WebSocket' .

Comment: Please accept the answer and ask a new question with more details about WebSocket